# Unexpected token exporting async function

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I am new to javascript and node. I do not understand why am I getting the following error.

The getList function works. I confirmed this by commenting out the export expression and enabling the call to the getlist function.

I am using node v10.15.1.

```
test.js:27
export async function vList() {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

-

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
  user: 'sa',
  password: 'pwd',
  server: '192.168.10.24',
  database: 'vmaint'
};

let aList;

async function getList() {
  try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let result = await pool
      .request()
      .query('SELECT item1, item2, item3, item4 FROM items');

    aList = result.recordset;
    console.dir(aList);
    pool.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

export async function vList() {
  if (!aList) {
    await getList();
  }
  if (!aList) {
    throw new Error('Could not get items');
  }
  return aList;
}
// getList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be setting module.exports and not using export right there.

Update that to be:

```
async function vList() {
   if (!aList) {
      await getList();
   }
   if (!aList) {
      throw new Error('Could not get items');
   }
   return aList;
}

module.exports = vList; // Changed line
```